# How to put "/" on a date values?

Tags: excel

what excel formula should I use to change a date value that is numbered into a date format. For example

5312018 into 5/31/2018
or 10202018 into 10/20/2018

See also image example below.

[image]

Comment: Curious how one will decide `1112018`? Will it be `11/1/2018` or `1/11/2018`? What is your rule for such cases?

Comment: I guess that would be 1/11/2018 looking at the other examples.

Comment: Its easy enough to manipulate and build strings in Excel but the problem you are going to have is that do the day and month parts have padding when the length is less than 2 bytes?  If not then you can't determine where a month and day start and end.

Comment: Some playing around with `Mod()` and `Quotient()` worksheet functions might get you quite far :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=8,LEFT(A2,2),LEFT(A2,1)) & "/" & IF(LEN(A2)=8,MID(A2,3,2),MID(A2,2,2)) & "/" & RIGHT(A2,4)
```

**Results:**

[image]